# BR() not returning a line break in flows

Tags: visual-flows, critical-update, line-break, textarea

As per [Use the BR() Function in Flows and Processes Correctly (Critical Update)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_cruc_br.htm), I am expecting BR() should return a line break. Through flow loop element, I am populating text area field. After each iteration, it was adding a BR() after each line. But in field it shows as 
 between lines, not a line break. I have activated the critical update for the same. Issue still persist.

Adding line break in flows.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by updating the data type of the field.

Previously it was *Long Text Area*. Now I have updated to *Rich Text Area*.

Now `<br>` returns a line break.

Comment: This is the only working solution I've been able to find as well. Super annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Text Template Resource Type.

And store the text with 
 there.

Note** if the field is not Rich Text, the value stores with HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial - https://goravseth.com/manipulating-text-in-flows

Basically create a text template with an embedded line break, then embed that text template into your assigned text wherever you want the line break to appear.

When creating the text template, make sure to make it "view as plain-text", otherwise you will get the paragraph mark html.

Answer (score -1):

Presently BR () is working in flows as a separator also for a Long Text Area field, just input BR () straight into a text formula. Example:
'Text '+ BR() + 'Text'

Comment: No - this is inaccurate.