List product on opportunity record
I have a user request to create a text field on the Opportunity object that will list all the Products related to that Opportunity in a text list.
How can I do this? Is it a flow?

Use DLRS that can roll up children into a concatenated text field - no code or flow required

Not the best solution, but you could solve it with a Flow.

Get all OpportunityLineItem related to the Opportunity, store them in a Record Collection Variable
Loop Record Collection Variable -> Assign requested Value (I presume the Name of the Product) by adding it into Opp.CustomFieldVariable (Text Type, consider to add Line truncation /br)
Update Opportunity Record, assigning Opp.CuastomFieldVariable Value to the Opp.Custom Field

Considerations:

Think of the Trigger for this Action, mainly to decide when this Field should be Updated (Condition Requirements)


How would I add the truncation exactly?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_cruc_br.htm&release=220&type=5

Create Forumula vith Text Type: BR()
Refer Formuila Variable at the end of the Value in your Assignment, where you add LineItems to the Variable

I have also found this referenced in this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298222/br-not-returning-a-line-break-in-flows#:~:text=Presently%20BR%20%28%29%20is%20working%20in%20flows%20as,formula.%20Example%3A%20%27Text%20%27%2B%20BR%20%28%29%20%2B%20%27Text%27
